# How to get JSON 3rd level deep data inside jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am getting this JSON response from a web site

```
{
    "HotelListResponse": {
        "customerSessionId": "0ABAAA7A-90C9-7491-3FF2-7E2C37496CA2",
        "numberOfRoomsRequested": 1,
        "moreResultsAvailable": true,
        "cacheKey": "7790c974:13ff7e2c374:6ccd",
        "cacheLocation": "10.186.170.122:7300",
        "HotelList": {
            "@activePropertyCount": "223",
            "@size": "1",
            "HotelSummary": {
                "@order": "0",
                "hotelId": 125727,
                "name": "Red Lion Hotel on Fifth Avenue",
                "address1": "1415 5th Ave",
                "city": "Seattle",
                "stateProvinceCode": "WA",
                "postalCode": 98101,
                "countryCode": "US",
                "airportCode": "SEA",
                "supplierType": "E",
                "propertyCategory": 1,
                "hotelRating": 3.5,
                "confidenceRating": 90,
                "amenityMask": 7847938,
                "tripAdvisorRating": 4,
                "locationDescription": "Near Pike Place Market",
                "shortDescription": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location. &lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Red Lion Hotel on Fifth Avenue is located close to 5th Avenue Theater, Pike Place Market, and Washington State Convention &amp; Trade Center. Additional points of interest",
                "highRate": 149,
                "lowRate": 126.65,
                "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
                "latitude": 47.60985,
                "longitude": -122.33475,
                "proximityDistance": 11.168453,
                "proximityUnit": "MI",
                "hotelInDestination": true,
                "thumbNailUrl": "/hotels/1000000/60000/51000/50947/50947_180_t.jpg",
                "deepLink": "http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&amp;cid=55505&amp;hotelID=125727&amp;mode=2&amp;numberOfRooms=1&amp;room-0-adult-total=2&amp;room-0-child-total=0&amp;arrivalMonth=8&amp;arrivalDay=4&amp;departureMonth=8&amp;departureDay=5&amp;showInfo=true&amp;locale=en_US&amp;currencyCode=USD",
                "RoomRateDetailsList": {
                    "RoomRateDetails": {
                        "roomTypeCode": 253461,
                        "rateCode": 201054304,
                        "maxRoomOccupancy": 2,
                        "quotedRoomOccupancy": 2,
                        "minGuestAge": 0,
                        "roomDescription": "Classic Single Queen",
                        "promoId": 202161947,
                        "promoDescription": "Summer Sale! Save 15%",
                        "currentAllotment": 0,
                        "propertyAvailable": true,
                        "propertyRestricted": false,
                        "expediaPropertyId": 50947,
                        "rateKey": "0ABAAA7A-90C9-7491-3FF2-7E2C37496CCE",
                        "RateInfo": {
                            "@rateChange": "false",
                            "@promo": "true",
                            "@priceBreakdown": "true",
                            "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                                "@total": "151.23",
                                "@surchargeTotal": "24.58",
                                "@nightlyRateTotal": "126.65",
                                "@maxNightlyRate": "126.65",
                                "@currencyCode": "USD",
                                "@commissionableUsdTotal": "126.65",
                                "@averageRate": "126.65",
                                "@averageBaseRate": "149.0",
                                "NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
                                    "@size": "1",
                                    "NightlyRate": {
                                        "@promo": "true",
                                        "@rate": "126.65",
                                        "@baseRate": "149.0"
                                    }
                                },
                                "Surcharges": {
                                    "@size": "1",
                                    "Surcharge": {
                                        "@amount": "24.58",
                                        "@type": "TaxAndServiceFee"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ValueAdds": {
                            "@size": "1",
                            "ValueAdd": {
                                "@id": "2048",
                                "description": "Free Wireless Internet"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to feed jqGrid with only 3rd level deep fields(under 'HotelSummary') like hotelId, name, or address1.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as its a JSON object you can use dot notation, if it is a string not an object then you need to parse is using JSON.parse() (accepted by most newer browsers)

```
response.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EaWJY/

UPDATED:

I used this to generate a row from the JSON data provided:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
        datatype : "local",
        height : 250,
        colNames : ['ID', 'Hotel ID', 'Name', 'Address 1'],
        colModel : [{
                name : 'id',
                index : 'id',
                width : 60,
                sorttype : "int"
            }, {
                name : 'hotelId',
                index : 'hotelId',
                width : 60,
                sorttype : "int"
            }, {
                name : 'name',
                index : 'name',
                width : 100
            }, {
                name : 'address1',
                index : 'address1',
                width : 100
            }
        ],
        multiselect : true,
        caption : "Hotel Data"
    });

    var response = {
        "HotelListResponse" : {
            "customerSessionId" : "0ABAAA7A-90C9-7491-3FF2-7E2C37496CA2",
            "numberOfRoomsRequested" : 1,
            "moreResultsAvailable" : true,
            "cacheKey" : "7790c974:13ff7e2c374:6ccd",
            "cacheLocation" : "10.186.170.122:7300",
            "HotelList" : {
                "@activePropertyCount" : "223",
                "@size" : "1",
                "HotelSummary" : {
                    "@order" : "0",
                    "hotelId" : 125727,
                    "name" : "Red Lion Hotel on Fifth Avenue",
                    "address1" : "1415 5th Ave",
                    "city" : "Seattle",
                    "stateProvinceCode" : "WA",
                    "postalCode" : 98101,
                    "countryCode" : "US",
                    "airportCode" : "SEA",
                    "supplierType" : "E",
                    "hotelRating" : 3.5,
                    "propertyCategory" : 1,
                    "confidenceRating" : 90,
                    "amenityMask" : 7847938,
                    "tripAdvisorRating" : 4,
                    "locationDescription" : "Near Pike Place Market",
                    "shortDescription" : "&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location. &lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Red Lion Hotel on Fifth Avenue is located close to 5th Avenue Theater, Pike Place Market, and Washington State Convention &amp; Trade Center. Additional points of interest",
                    "highRate" : 149,
                    "lowRate" : 126.65,
                    "rateCurrencyCode" : "USD",
                    "latitude" : 47.60985,
                    "longitude" : -122.33475,
                    "proximityDistance" : 11.168453,
                    "proximityUnit" : "MI",
                    "hotelInDestination" : true,
                    "thumbNailUrl" : "/hotels/1000000/60000/51000/50947/50947_180_t.jpg",
                    "deepLink" : "http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&amp;cid=55505&amp;hotelID=125727&amp;mode=2&amp;numberOfRooms=1&amp;room-0-adult-total=2&amp;room-0-child-total=0&amp;arrivalMonth=8&amp;arrivalDay=4&amp;departureMonth=8&amp;departureDay=5&amp;showInfo=true&amp;locale=en_US&amp;currencyCode=USD",
                    "RoomRateDetailsList" : {
                        "RoomRateDetails" : {
                            "roomTypeCode" : 253461,
                            "rateCode" : 201054304,
                            "maxRoomOccupancy" : 2,
                            "quotedRoomOccupancy" : 2,
                            "minGuestAge" : 0,
                            "roomDescription" : "Classic Single Queen",
                            "promoId" : 202161947,
                            "promoDescription" : "Summer Sale! Save 15%",
                            "currentAllotment" : 0,
                            "propertyAvailable" : true,
                            "propertyRestricted" : false,
                            "expediaPropertyId" : 50947,
                            "rateKey" : "0ABAAA7A-90C9-7491-3FF2-7E2C37496CCE",
                            "RateInfo" : {
                                "@rateChange" : "false",
                                "@promo" : "true",
                                "@priceBreakdown" : "true",
                                "ChargeableRateInfo" : {
                                    "@total" : "151.23",
                                    "@surchargeTotal" : "24.58",
                                    "@nightlyRateTotal" : "126.65",
                                    "@maxNightlyRate" : "126.65",
                                    "@currencyCode" : "USD",
                                    "@commissionableUsdTotal" : "126.65",
                                    "@averageRate" : "126.65",
                                    "@averageBaseRate" : "149.0",
                                    "NightlyRatesPerRoom" : {
                                        "@size" : "1",
                                        "NightlyRate" : {
                                            "@promo" : "true",
                                            "@rate" : "126.65",
                                            "@baseRate" : "149.0"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Surcharges" : {
                                        "@size" : "1",
                                        "Surcharge" : {
                                            "@amount" : "24.58",
                                            "@type" : "TaxAndServiceFee"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "ValueAdds" : {
                                "@size" : "1",
                                "ValueAdd" : {
                                    "@id" : "2048",
                                    "description" : "Free Wireless Internet"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var rows = jQuery('#list4').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');

    var hotelInfo = response.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;
    var rowData = {};
    rowData.id = rows + 1;
    rowData.hotelId = hotelInfo.hotelId;
    rowData.name = hotelInfo.name;
    rowData.address1 = hotelInfo.address1;

    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData', rows + 1, rowData);
});
```

Comment: Can u post an example with jqGrid?

Comment: Now I am trying to find a way to pass the response variable inside javascript (it is an EL variable - ${message})

Comment: If your JS file is an external file, IE your importing it, then put something like this above the import on your JSP page <script type="text/javascript">var name = '${message}';</script> That way you can reference that variable in the JS file by the variable name

Comment: I really don't get what r u talking about in this last comment.Can you be more specific please?